# Why does Paint sometimes change the color of a part of the image?

Tags: colors, microsoft-paint

Sometimes, Paint changes the RGB value of the color of a group of pixels in a PNG image when it gets saved. It only changes a little bit, for example from RGB(128,128,128) to RGB(127,127,127), so you can't see it just by looking at the picture, but you can notice it when using the Fill function for example.

To show you a concrete example of this, here is a picture of a 256x256 square which was originally completely filled with RGB(128,128,128) gray, and some parts have when saving the image become RGB(127,127,127) or RGB(126,126,126). To make the difference visible, I've colored the RGB(128,128,128) in white, the RGB(127,127,127) in gray, and the RGB(126,126,126) in black.

[image]

Why does it do this?

Comment: Potentially for this reason http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/color-settings/

Comment: Also it will due to the compression PAINT uses when saving the image!

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, it may code something like your ip into an image file

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography

Comment: An image processing program doesn't mess with the image contents to store meta data.